# Change font color of row of 2 dimension array in js

Tags: javascript, css

I am a js beginner and I am trying to change the color of several rows if those meet a condition. I am coding on a cloud based platform that we have access at work. We use js to generate a dashboard app which pulls the data that comes from pyspark dataframes and transform it into an array (JSON format I guess). I have no problem using python, but I do have trouble manipulating the data in js. So, to give you an idea, this is how the rendering of my table looks like:
[image]

Now presented below is my code:

```
var data = {{q_final_dataset_clean}};

for (var i = 0; i < data["ratio"].length; i++){
    if (data["ratio"][i]< 1){
        data[i].className="isbelow";// we do change the color of the row
    }
    else{
        data[i]//we do not change the color
    }
}
return data;
```

[image]

And the CSS styling:
[image]

Can someone help please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show all code as text, in a [mre], not as pictures of text. The CSS is not valid CSS; it is likely SCSS or LESS which is compiled to CSS. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) once you have the compiled CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: As your css show your are changing the color of the font and not the color of the background. The css property for this is background-color. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background-color